# Can not create alias `IF` or `IFNULL`

Tags: h2, h2db

I am trying to create an alias in H2database for `IF` and I get the following error.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Function alias "IF" already exists; SQL statement:

CREATE ALIAS `IF` FOR "test.Udf.ifAlias" [90076-212]
```

Then I try to drop the `IF` before creating, and I get the following error.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Function alias "IF" not found; SQL statement:

DROP ALIAS `IF` [90077-212]
```

Similar happens for `IFNULL`. I am trying the following lines in my init script.

```
DROP ALIAS `IF`;
CREATE ALIAS `IF` FOR "test.Udf.ifAlias";
```

And the Java function for the `ifAlias` is

```
  public static boolean ifAlias(boolean condition, boolean exp1, boolean exp2) {
    if(condition) {
      return exp1;
    }
    return exp2;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.4.198, IF is a keyword in h2. See this issue and responses: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3018